# Filter date to display order in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display data for the date 20141211 to 20141214. but there is an error.

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDER_DATE >= '20141211'
  AND ORDER_DATE < '20141214'
```

but doesn't seem to work.

```
"ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal."
```

the filter detail of data between 20141211 to 20141214.

Comment: you are using sql server or mysql, etc?

Comment: Oracle SQL server

Comment: The problem is that `order_date` is a `DATE` column and you compare it with a string literal. Oracle tries to convert the string into a date, but fails to guess your format. Don't leave that to chance. Always use date literals (e.g. `DATE '2014-12-11'`) when working with fixed dates.

Comment: A little side note: Queries can become hard to read when they are in all upper case. Some people use all lower case, which is much easier to read, because in English most words are in lower case, so the brain is used to that. Some people write keywords in upper case and table and column names in lower case, which is another way to increase readability.

Comment: @Prisilya "Oracle" and "Microsoft SQL Server" are two different products, so "Oracle SQL server" is like "Sony Series X" or "Microsoft PS5" :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is complaining about the date literals.  Use valid Oracle literals and your query should work:

```java
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN date '2014-12-11' AND date '2014-12-14';
```

Comment: The sample query has `>= '20141211'` and `< '20141214'`, which is `BETWEEN DATE '2014-12-11' AND DATE '2014-12-13'`, not `'2014-12-14'`. I think it is a good habit to work with `>=` and `<` when working with dates and datetimes (especially in Oracle where there exists no date type but only a datetime type they call `DATE` unfortunately). But, well, the column name `order_date` suggests a date only, so you should be fine with `BETWEEN DATE '2014-12-11' AND DATE '2014-12-13'`.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts, and I also had doubts as to the OP's intention.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In Oracle a `DATE` data type has both date and time components. Suggesting `BETWEEN DATE '2014-12-11' AND DATE '2014-12-13'` is only correct if the OP has a `CHECK` constraint on the column that enforces that the column always has a time component at midnight; otherwise the OP's filter is "correct" (ignoring the use of string literals) and you do want to use `>= DATE '2014-12-11'` and `< DATE '2014-12-14'` to get the entire 24 hour period for for 2014-12-13 (and ignore 2014-12-14 00:00:00, which this answer erroneously includes in the range).

Comment: @MT0: This is what I was trying to say :-) Provided order_**date** is not a misnomer, `BETWEEN` would be okay, but it is better to always use `>=` and `<` when dealing with dates and datetimes. A check constraint on `DATE` columns that are supposed to be real date columns and not datetime columns is a great idea and would be my recommendation, too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to format your date as number (getting ridd of time component in the same time):

```sql
...
WHERE To_Number(To_Char(ORDER_DATE, 'yyyymmdd')) BETWEEN 20141211 AND 20141214
```

Or, if it is not between (it takes both values like >= and <=) but >= and < then:

```sql
...
WHERE To_Number(To_Char(ORDER_DATE, 'yyyymmdd')) >= 20141211 AND 
      To_Number(To_Char(ORDER_DATE, 'yyyymmdd')) <  20141214
```

... or whatever else comparison you might need...

Comment: If you don't have a function-based index on the column, then depending on the table size, this may trigger a full table scan

Comment: @OldProgrammer That is true, but we know nothing about the size, description, indexes, constraints - anything regarding the table... This is just one of the options - as stated in the answer.